# Order by something, then random?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query, something like this:

`..ORDER BY photo.sort_order DESC, profile.description DESC, RAND()`

So this means, records with photos are shown first, then those with descriptions. Within that I want the order to be random (so if there's ten records with photos, they should always be at the top but ordered randomly)

The above doesn't work and I know rand() is not great performance wise. What would be another simple solution?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: the order doesn't change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably want change your select a bit to take the desc txt out of the equation since you're only interested in whether it's null.

```
 select photo.sort_order,
        profile.description is not null as desc_order,
        profile.description,
        rand() as r
 from
        photo photo, profile profile
order by 
        photo.sort_order desc, 
        desc_order desc, 
        r
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily add desc_order and r to the `select` clause if you don't need the actual values as it adds to the amount of data being transferred. Just add the expressions themselves to the `order by` clause.